# Cant understand Rsync errors using ssh

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, rsync

I want to tryout Rsync for the first time but have run into difficulty.

I want to transfer files from a remote server to my local server.

I login to my local server and type:

```
sudo rsync -avz ssh ubuntu@xx.xxx.xx.xx /var/www/html/mywebsite.co.uk /var/www/html/
```

Which means I want to to copy the folder 'mywebsite.co.uk' from the remote server into the /var/www/html folder on my local server.

Both severs are configured to use the same ssh key.

I get the following errors:

```
sending incremental file list
rsync: link_stat "/var/www/html/ssh" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: link_stat "/var/www/html/ubuntu@xx.xxx.xxx.xx" failed: No such file or directory (2)

sent 55 bytes  received 13 bytes  136.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1070) [sender=3.0.9]
```

Can anybody help me understand these errors?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `-e "ssh ubuntu@a.b.c.d"` instead of just `ssh ubuntu@a.b.c.d`.

Comment: Thats worked! But now I get the error: Permission denied (publickey).

Comment: Then I submit that you don't, in fact, have working keys.

Answer (score 3):

Your syntax is incorrect. Should be

```
sudo rsync -avz -e ssh ubuntu@xx.xxx.xx.xx:/var/www/html/mywebsite.co.uk /var/www/html/
```

Missing the -e operator for ssh. And you need colon after the ip address.

Answer (score 0):

When specifying a remote location with **SSH** (which require `-e ssh`, otherwise it uses rsync own protocol and requires rsync server/daemon to be started on the other end), you have to write it following this pattern :

```
[user@]short_name[.domain]:[path]
```

If you ommit `user@` it willl assume the remote user is the same that the one used on the local machine
If you ommit `.domain` it will use your domain search settings (like any other name resolution)
If you omit `path` it will use the remote user's home directory (Note: it's the same as writing `user@server:~` )

So here, you just have to replace the space  by a colon `:` like Grumpy wrote it in his answer.

Comment: Thats worked! But now I get the error: Permission denied (publickey).

Answer (score 0):

try below syntax

```
rsync -e ssh -avz ubuntu@xx.xxx.xx.xx:/var/www/html/mywebsite.co.uk root@50.23.148.226:/var/www/html/
```

Also you can include ssh key & port if required

```
rsync -e "ssh -p PORT_NO -i path_to_file" -avz ubuntu@xx.xxx.xx.xx:/var/www/html/mywebsite.co.uk root@xx.xx.xxx.xx:/var/www/html/
```

Comment: You might want to remove your IP from your answer...